# Does Windows 8 installation create a 100-MB-Bitlocker partition on second HDD as Windows 7 did?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-installation, bitlocker

I upgraded my computer (Acer Aspire V3-771G) by adding a SSD. Now I want to make a clean install of Windows 8 on this new SSD. The HDD should be cleaned/formatted and later be used for a Linux OS (probably openSUSE 12.3).

From Windows 7 installation I remember, that it automatically uses 2 HDD, if recognized. One HDD for the OS partition and one for the 100-MB-Bitlocker partition. If there is only one harddisk, the Bitlocker partition was placed on the same harddisk as the OS partition.

The formatted HDD should stay clean after Windows 8 installation.
Does anyone know, if Windows 8 also automatically uses 2 HDD for some partitions, if available?
If so, what could I do, to avoid that (without disassembling my computer again removing one HDD)?

Comment: Windows 8 shouldn't automatically do anything.  In my personal experience it provides you a chance to change the location of the Bitlocker partition location.

Comment: @ Ramhound Infact it does. I now installed Windows 8 and left the the second hard disk unformatted. On this second hard disk are the recovery partition (300 MB) and the efi partition (100 MB) located. The rest of the space is still unformatted.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I installed everything again and formatted all partitions (by selecting each and clicking "Format") after I introduced the new OS partition. Was that the secret? Because now it worked fine: the other hard disk is still completely untouched and recovery and efi partitions are on same hard disk as the OS.